# Allow 'Set featured images' to select multiple images

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

So 'Featured image' option on WP is lacking. What I was expecting is when user selects multiple images it echos out multiple images on the page, instead you can only select one photo. I tried to find some plugin to do **exactly** that, but no luck. It seems easy to do and I wouldn't like any additional plugins.

Can anybody do that so when I type

`<?php the_post_thumbnails('index-thumb'); ?>`

it returns:

```
<img src="..."...
<img src="..."...
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you! ;)

Comment: If it's easy to do, what's the problem? ;) The featured image functionality is for just that - a single featured image. If you want more, try the Multiple Post Thumbnails plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its certainly not a few liner code. So its better to use a [Feature Gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-galleries/screenshots/) plugin. I just tried that which works perfectly fine and you can use below code to get the images in Featured Gallery.

```
<?php $galleryArray = get_post_gallery_ids($post->ID);  
      foreach ($galleryArray as $id) { ?>   
         <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $id ); ?>"> 
<?php }?>
```

Please refer plugin description to get more details about the code.

Comment: I'll try to implement it into my code and let you know how it goes. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Installed the plugin, but how to make a 'featured gallery post' a custom post type? Tried to insert the code author of the plugin gave into functions.php but it breaks the plugin. My loop looks like this `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );` so it's capable of custom post formats. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think there must be some mistake in code which you used provided by plugin author. Most probably you forgot to change the slug as per the actual post format. Please refer below code wherein I used 'header-image' slug of my custom post type and that worked fine.
`function add_featured_galleries_to_ctp( $post_types ) {
 return array('header-image');
}
add_filter('fg_post_types', 'add_featured_galleries_to_ctp' );`

Comment: Did it work or you are still facing problem?

Comment: I used `if ( !empty(get_post_gallery_ids($post->ID)) )` to differentiate if post has featured gallery or not, imo better way than creating additional post type, and having user to select the post type. Took me like half of day to figure this out but it works great. Thanks for your answer it pointed me in the right direction. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome & I am glad I could help you out.